# Angular Instantiate components more times

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using angular 6 and i can't instantiate a components more than one time, I have tryed to see similar question on stack overflow but I didn't find answer

here is **html-div-component.html**

```
<div [style.opacity]="opacity" class='div-component' [style.margin- top.px]="marginTop">
```

and **html-div.component.ts**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-html-div',
   templateUrl: './html-div.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./html-div.component.css']
})     
export class HtmlDivComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name;

  @ViewChildren('div-component') elements: QueryList<HtmlDivComponent>;

  ...

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('initializing');
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler, true);
    window.onload = (event) => {
    ...
  };

 }
 ...
}
```

Here the parent component .html

```
<app-html-div id="get-started-div" name="blue">
<div class="charat-list default-panel mui-panel">
  <h2 class="forstyle-h2">/h2>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="2">
  </p>
</div>
</app-html-div>
<app-html-div name="green">
<div class="charat-list default-panel mui-panel">
  <h2 class="forstyle-h2"></h2>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="1">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="2">
  </p>
</div>
```

in my log console i see this

```
initializing
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `ngOnInit()` will be triggered only once when component is loaded. what is the issue you are facing exactly?

Comment: I have called 2 times the component and ngOnInit() is triggered only one time, see my html parent component

Comment: it will console two components , please check this code sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwae9v?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Could you please reproduce it in some live-example (stackblitz?) as i see no reason not to work (

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano, are you seeing any console.log errors?

Comment: the problem is in my console.log from the class

Comment: no i can't see any errors

Comment: i have reproduced the problem in stackblitz

Comment: Can you help me saving changes to stackblitz?

Comment: @AlesandroGiordano, please share stackblitz link

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icsexz

Comment: just click save or fork it and give that link, make sure you logged in :)

Comment: you can see that the number generated by the instance is the same in each components, I have to handle this separatly for each component

Comment: it is consoling two times - 2 test..number -2 indicates it consoles two times

Comment: Yes but the number is the same, this mean that the code was running one time

Comment: no it means , it ran two times, as it is consoling same value, it showing as consolidated one text, but number it ran is indicated bby number 2 , try this to see difference - console.log("test", Math.random()) - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvaleu?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: thank you, there is any reason why you have used an @Input?

Comment: you can try with alert and console, just to test from your side  and at the same time check in developer tools for console

Comment: Ok thank you, now I'll try to reproduce this on my application and I will tell you about results

Comment: sure @AlesandroGiordano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed over comments, console log in ngOnInit will be consoled in browser developer tools as many times as the component used

codesample - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwae9v?file=src/app/app.component.html
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvaleu?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

In your case, it is not issue with the application but the browser developer tools is designed to stack repeated console messages to one and show the number for the repetition

Check this link for reference - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/  as per Chrome documentation

**Message stacking**
If a message is consecutively repeated, rather than printing out each instance of the message on a new line, the Console "stacks" the messages and shows a number in the left margin instead. The number indicates how many times the message has repeated.

Just for testing and understanding , try this simple example

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    alert("test")
    console.log("test")
}

//ouput you will see in console as 3 test, you will see three alert windows
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think that was my problem.

Comment: Glad it solved yout prolem, please do not forget mark my post as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the second instance of `<app-html-div>` rendering?

It is possible that your first instance of HtmlDivComponent initializes, runs, and fails. If there was a problem in the first instance of the component, that may prevent the rest of the application from loading.

Comment: Yes it was rendered